# Download prior iOS versions using apple developer license offically

Tags: ios, download

I have purchased and am enrolled in the apple developer program; does anyone know or have a link to the direct downloads for prior iOS versions so that I could, for instance, download iOS 5 officially?

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, Apple removes ios restore images from public access as soon as a new version is released. The only way I see is to load the images for every version and every device before they disappear. But I understand it's not an answer how to get such old OS.

Comment: It's up to you :) But don't know more helpful answer.